# performance of operator>>(istream&, double) VC10/VC11

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, visual-studio-2012

Switching from VC10 to VC11 I observe a performance drop of a factor 10 when reading a file with `double` numbers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  double sum = 0, x;
  for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
    std::cin >> x;
    sum += x;
  }
  std::cerr << sum << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I built the executable in Developer Studio, so that the environment chooses the options in release mode at best.

Can anybody confirm this?
What could be the problem? Might it be related to `locale`?

thanks in advance,

andreas

Comment: I wonder why are you using a text file to store a million of double numbers.

Comment: In reality I read the x y z coordinate of points, and I also do something better than just summing the  numbers up, but that is just distracting from my question.

Comment: That's very cool and still doesn't answer my question

Comment: I avoid whenever possible use stream, homemade solutions are much more efficient than generic models.

Comment: ... and assembler is better than C++.   I am sorry but that is not the point here. I just want a confirmation by some other people who have VC10 and VC11 on their machine, if they also observe a slowdown in the IO of dobubles.

Answer (score 0):

*for some reason my previous answer was deleted (I do admit that the first sentence was a bit confusing, due to a clumsy edit when it got better results)

Actually, for me the performance is about the same.

VC11 writing/reading 1M doubles -> 6.600/3.562 seconds
VC10 writing/reading 1M doubles -> 6.266/3.606 seconds

So in my experiment, reading doubles from file in vc11 is aprox. the same performance as with vc10.
Codesample:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  auto x = 0.0;
  auto numberofdoubles = 1000000;
  auto filename = "C:\\double.txt";

  {
  std::ofstream filestr(filename);
  auto starttime = clock();
  for(int i=0; i<numberofdoubles; i++)
    filestr << (double)i << " ";

  auto endtime = clock();
  auto elapsed = (double)(endtime - starttime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << "writing: " << elapsed << std::endl;
  }

  {
  std::ifstream filestr (filename);
  auto starttime = clock();
  for(int i=0; i<numberofdoubles; i++)
    filestr >> x;

  auto endtime = clock();
  auto elapsed = (double)(endtime - starttime)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << "reading: " << elapsed << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```